# how to set data-selection to a Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that changes the check selection on click and also applies the default check to the `input` with checked within

**example**

```
<input type='checkbox' class='regular-checkbox big-checkbox multicheck' data-paysys="" checked/>
```

**and my jquery function**

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == 'singlecheck') {
            if ($('input.multicheck').is(":checked")) {
                $('#warning').show();
            }
            $('input.multicheck').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('input.singlecheck').prop('checked', false);
            $('#warning').hide();
        }
    });
```

How can I set the `checked`to be set via `$accordion.data("selection")`instead so I can use

```
<div id="accordion-test" data-selection="2">
```

**what I have tried**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == 'singlecheck') {
            if ($('input.multicheck').is($accordion.data("selection"))) {
                $('#warning').show();
            }
            $('input.multicheck').prop($accordion.data("selection"), false);
        } else {
            $('input.singlecheck').prop($accordion.data("selection"), false);
            $('#warning').hide();
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE ADDED FIDDEL**

here is a fiddel im working on, as you can see the accordion is open as data-selection - "1" but the check is still not on the correct one.

https://jsfiddle.net/rqzgjnwc/#&togetherjs=t0SOlQwIr9

Comment: Have you tried like this,             if ($('input.multicheck').is(":"+$accordion.data("selection"))) {

Comment: hmm, nice this could work. how could i configure this with my current code ?

Comment: So what you want is :  Whichever accordian is active, its checked box should be checked right ?

Comment: yes, perfect with the data-selection determining the active accordion

Comment: Its like an index of array like, first will be 0 and second will be 1, so data-selection=2 means 3rd one, getting me ?

Comment: yeah that is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133352/discussion-between-v-for-vendetta-and-benjamin-oats).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == 'singlecheck') {
            if ($('input.multicheck').is(":"+$accordion.data("selection"))) {
                $('#warning').show();
            }
            $('input.multicheck').prop($accordion.data("selection"), false);
        } else {
            $('input.singlecheck').prop($accordion.data("selection"), false);
            $('#warning').hide();
        }
    });
```

Let me know if it is working.

**EDIT**

```
$(function() {
   var $accordion = $("#accordion");
   $accordion.accordion({
     autoHeight: true,
     collapsible: true,
     active: $accordion.data("selection"),
     change: function(event, ui) {
       makeChecked();
     },
     create: function(event, ui) {
       makeChecked();
     }
   });
 });

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

   if ($(this).attr("class") == 'singlecheck') {
     if ($('input.multicheck').is(":checked")) {
       $('#warning').show();
     }
     $('input.multicheck').prop('checked', false);
   } else {
     $('input.singlecheck').prop('checked', false);
     $('#warning').hide();
   }
 });

 function makeChecked() {
   $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
   $("lable.ui-state-active").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
 }
```

For working code, once check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqzgjnwc/2/) link.

Comment: hmm seems close to the method i was trying, not working as of yet, but ill keep trying.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle, I will give you working code.

Comment: hmm lots of code lol, ill try and get a basic one up and running